# How to create class to establish database connection using establish_connection - RUBY

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I don't know much about Ruby language. I am trying to create a class to establish an oracle database connection. This class will receive the connection to be reused in other classes. I am working on an automation project and need to establish this connection in order to prepare the mass of data for automated testing. Below I will make my code available so that someone can guide me how I should create this class. In this case it is not possible to access the connection class.

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"

class Connection
    attr_accessor :connection

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "oracle_enhanced",
    :database => "dboraclehomolog.com.br:1521/homolog",
    :username => "USER",
    :password => "password",
  )

  def initialize
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  end

  def execute_select(sql)
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

    if results.nil?
      return results
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def exec(sql)
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
    rescue => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
end
```

ERROR: uninitialized constant Repactuar::Conexao (NameError)

Comment: please update question to include full backtrace errors, but also, what do you mean by " it is not possible to access the connection class" ?

Comment: The error presented on the console is just this. Which makes it even harder for me. I don't know if the code does not agree with language conventions.

When I say that it is not possible to access the connection class is as follows. In the class I want to use the 'exec' method of the connection class. The daughter class cannot see the exec method.

Comment: what do you mean by "daughter class"  is there another class which inherits from this?  If so, you should include it in your question.